# How to deal with little o-notation when we apply Taylor's formula

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

Like in this example, how did we manage to get $o(x^5)$ at the end? Do we expand the 2 brackets without letting $o(x^5)$ to be involved, or do we mutiply the little-o s with all the terms like a normal term?

$$\begin{aligned}\tan x &=\left[x-\frac{x^{3}}{3 !}+\frac{x^{5}}{5 !}+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] \cdot\left[1-\left(-\frac{x^{2}}{2 !}+\frac{x^{4}}{4 !}\right)+\left(\frac{x^{4}}{4}\right)-(0)+(0)-(0)+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] \\
&=\left[x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{x^{5}}{120}+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] \cdot\left[1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{5 \cdot x^{4}}{24}+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] \\
&=\left(x \cdot 1+x \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}+x \cdot \frac{5 x^{4}}{24}\right)+\left(-\frac{x^{3}}{6} \cdot 1-\frac{x^{3}}{6} \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}-\frac{x^{3}}{6} \cdot \frac{5 x^{4}}{24}\right)+\left(\frac{x^{5}}{120} \cdot 1+\frac{x^{5}}{120} \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{x^{5}}{120} \cdot \frac{5 x^{4}}{24}\right)+o\left(x^{5}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

This is the whole exercice:

[image: Don't mind about the added handwriting in the picture]
**Don't mind about the added handwriting in the picture**

Comment: All powers $>5$ will join $o(x^5)$.

Comment: yes I did that but I arrived at $o(x^6)$ at the end

Comment: $o(x^6)\subset o(x^5), x\to 0$.

Comment: zkutch -but how will i know that i should replace $o(x^6)$ with $o(x^5)$ because $o(x^6)\subset o(x^5), x\to 0$, i mean can't i leave it as $o(x^6)$? would it be wrong?

Comment: The $o(x^5)$ in the 1st bracket times the $1$ in the 2nd bracket gives you the $o(x^5)$ in the answer. If you got $o(x^6)$, you must have missed that.

Comment: Wait.. how? I know that $o(x^5)$ times $o(x^5)$ gives $o(x^(10))$, not $o(x^5)$

Comment: @ElieMakdissi sho lwd3 kfk wsho esmo lktb?

Comment: @aliberro ahlan kifk? khaye he l kteb l doctor 3emlo, w metel ma 2rit l post, isa btejma3 l little o's lezim ytla3 jaweb gher houwe li hotto

Comment: @aliberro meche l hol hon, 3ende sou2el tene isa fik tchoufo mn ba3ed amrak https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4305961/976331

Comment: @ElieMakdissi eh fe 8lt in his work

Comment: I didn't say $o(x^5)$ times $o(x^5)$; I said $o(x^5)$ times $1$. There's a $1$ in the 2nd bracket.

Comment: ah okay sorry mate @GerryMyerson

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shortly You are correct $o(g)o(f)=o(gf)$, but in $0$s neighborhood minimal little $o$ "**eat**" big powers, as pure ones, so inside in other little $o$.

Long way:

By definition little-$o$ is set of functions
$$o(g)=\{f: \exists \varepsilon(x), \lim\limits_{x \to x_0}\varepsilon(x)=0,  \exists \delta >0, \forall x \in  U_\delta(x_0), f(x)= \varepsilon(x) g(x) \}$$
More exactly we use notation $o(g(x)),x \to x_0$.

Using this definition let me proof, that
$$o\left(x^{5}\right)+o\left(x^{6}\right)=o\left(x^{5}\right),x \to 0\quad(1)$$
As we have equality between sets, then we need to show two-way inclusion: $\subset \land \supset$

1. Assume $\phi \in o\left(x^{5}\right)+o\left(x^{6}\right) \Rightarrow \phi=\varepsilon_1x^5+\varepsilon_2x^6=(\varepsilon_1+\varepsilon_2x)x^5=\varepsilon_3x^5\in o\left(x^{5}\right)$
2. $\phi \in o\left(x^{5}\right)\Rightarrow \phi=\varepsilon_1x^5-x^7+x^7$, where $\varepsilon_1x^5-x^7\in o\left(x^{5}\right)$ from $1$st case and $x^7\in o\left(x^{6}\right)$

Analogical proof gives $o\left(x^{5}\right)+x^{6}=o\left(x^{5}\right),x \to 0$. So, we obtain well known property: little $o\left(x^{5}\right)$ "**eat**" all powers as pure as well inside other little $o$, which are more, then $5$. So we obtain:
$$\left[x-\frac{x^{3}}{6}+\frac{x^{5}}{120}+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] \cdot\left[1+\frac{x^{2}}{2}+\frac{5 \cdot x^{4}}{24}+o\left(x^{5}\right)\right] =\\
=\left(x +x \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}+x \cdot \frac{5 x^{4}}{24}\right)+\left(-\frac{x^{3}}{6}-\frac{x^{3}}{6} \cdot \frac{x^{2}}{2}\right)+\frac{x^{5}}{120} +o\left(x^{5}\right)$$

Comment: And the $o(x^5)$ at the end comes from multiplying the $o(x^5)$ in the first bracket by the $1$ in the second bracket.